# Do I need a a special device to use an AP with POE with a home router?

Tags: access-point, power-over-ethernet

I am setting up a small network for my office, I have a ZTE F660 router which is provided by my ISP and I am considering buying a couple of LINKSYS LAPAC1200 with POE access points. My question is, do I need my current router to support this feature? or I just plug it and it's working?
Do I need another devices to power my AP with POE?

Comment: Questions about consumer grade equipment are off topic here. Please consider asking on [su].